# I am trying to sum up value of last column based on common key which is 1st 3 colums in the files

Tags: bash, awk

I am using awk to sum up the value of last column based on common key. Common key is the 1st 3 column of the text files.

File.txt

```
w13_2022,AAA,BBB,200
w13_2022,AAA,BBB,100
w39_2022,XXX,ZZZ,1280946.909
```

Expected result:

```
w39_2022,XXX,ZZZ,1280946.909
w13_2022,AAA,BBB,300
```

I used below command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]+=$4} END{for(i in a){print i OFS a[i]}}' file.txt
```

Result is as below by this command:

```
w39_2022,XXX,ZZZ,1.28095e+06
w13_2022,AAA,BBB,300
```

value for 1st line is not correct. Can someone help on this?

Result is coming

Comment: `awk` is formatting the output in scientific notation for the larger decimal number.  You can use `printf` rather than `print` to format the output.   Something like `printf i OFS "%.3f\n", a[i]`

Comment: Thanks a lot @j_b. It worked now with your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> value for 1st line is not correct.

It is correct, but shown in e-notation, set `OFMT` variable to inform GNU `AWK` that you want other notation, let `file.txt` content be

```
w13_2022,AAA,BBB,200
w13_2022,AAA,BBB,100
w39_2022,XXX,ZZZ,1280946.909
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";OFMT="%f"} {a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]+=$4} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
w39_2022,XXX,ZZZ,1280946.909000
w13_2022,AAA,BBB,300
```

Observe that beyond setting [`OFMT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/OFMT.html) I also use `,` with `print` rather than `OFS`, which is required here as otherwise `print` does detect it had single string to print rather than string and numeric value to format.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*